# SSRS parameter not in list when adding a new parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My original stored procedure only included three parameters:

```
@facilityId int = 0, 
@startDate date,
@endDate date
```

I've added a new parameter to give the user the ability to search based on a last name, so now my parameters look like:

```
@facilityId int = 0, 
@startDate date,
@endDate date,
@lastName nvarchar(255) = NULL
```

However, my report does not show the new parameter in either of my Parameters list or in the parameters section of the Datasets properties:

[image]
[image]

My new parameter is present when viewing the Shared Dataset Properties:

[image]

I've tried to delete the `report.rdl.data` file, closed/opened VS, rebuild the database connection, and refreshed fields.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to manually create a parameter with the same name as my stored procedure parameter. This allowed me to select as a drop down in the parameters section of the Data Set properties.

Regardless of how many times I tried to close/open VS, or delete the `.data` file, the new stored procedure would not populate.

Comment: Tried everything, and closing Visual Studio helped.